# How to get and enumerate all the object.empty_display_type in python?

Tags: python, objects, empty

I would like to build a enum function that returns me all types of empty_diplay_type that exist, I am aware of the ones that currently exist, but I am creating a property that needs to change the empty_diplay_type.

Unfortunately I don't know where to look in Blender API

This property is tied to the scene with a PointerProperty,
Then the callback fc looks for all empty and must change the type of empty.

Like this example:

```
empty_type_list=[]
def enum_empty_types(self, context):
    
    if empty_type_list:
        return empty_type_list
    
    for eType in ['PLAIN_AXES', 'ARROWS', 'SINGLE_ARROW']:  #etc. etc.
        empty_type_list.append((eType, eType.replace("_", " ").title(), ""))
    
    return empty_type_list
    
def update_empty_type(self, context):

    for o in context.scene.objects:
        if o.type == 'EMPTY':
            o.empty_display_type = self.empty_types


class MySceneProp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    empty_types: EnumProperty(items=enum_empty_types, update=update_empty_type)
```

Comment: Looking for `bpy.types.Object.bl_rna.properties['empty_display_type'].enum_items`?

Comment: @scurest Uh yes, so: bpy.types.Object.bl_rna.properties['empty_display_type'].enum_items.keys()

Please give this as an answer, so that I can give you the score as a valid answer, as you have found the answer to my question.